# Using regular expressions to change element names for dataframes in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of many dataframes, in which I'd like to change certain elements within the dataframes using regular expressions. Here is a shortened mock-up of my data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("KBS_2015_08_25_A1_P1", "KBS_2015_08_25_A2_P10", "KBS_2015_09_04_A2_P2"),
                  Site = c("KBS","KBS","KBS"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("UMBS_2015_08_12_A1_P1", "UMBS_2015_08_29_D3_P3", "UMBS_2015_08_29_D5_P5"),
                  Site = c("UMBS","UMBS","UMBS"))
df_list <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2)
```

I attempted to make a function that takes the information in the ID column and changes it to a character string of a date.

```
change_id <- function(df){
  df$ID[df$ID == "^KBS_2015_08_25*P\\d"] <- "8/25/2015"
  df$ID[df$ID == "^KBS_2015_09_04*P\\d"] <- "9/4/2015"
  df$ID[df$ID == "^UMBS_2015_08_12*P\\d"] <- "8/12/2015"
  df$ID[df$ID == "^UMBS_2015_08_29*P\\d"] <- "8/29/2015"
  return(df)
}

df_list <- lapply(df_list, change_id)
```

I don't get any errors, but this function doesn't change anything in the dataframes. I must be missing something for my attempt at character matching.

Using R version 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: Is your regex correct? `08_25*P` means the literal `08_2`, then zero or more `5`s, then the literal `P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
lapply(df_list, transform, ID = sub(".*_(\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2})_.*", "\\1", ID))
```

If needed to be in a specific format, convert to `Date` class and then use `format`

```
df_list1 <- lapply(df_list, transform, 
    ID = format(as.Date(sub(".*_(\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2})_.*",
               "\\1", ID), "%Y_%m_%d"), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

-output

```
df_list1
#$df1
#          ID Site
#1 08/25/2015  KBS
#2 08/25/2015  KBS
#3 09/04/2015  KBS

#$df2
#          ID Site
#1 08/12/2015 UMBS
#2 08/29/2015 UMBS
#3 08/29/2015 UMBS
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @akrun's excellent answer is a "join" methodology. The reason this can be good is so that the pattern/replacement list can be kept as a single frame/table, making maintenance a bit easier.

It operates by using `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`, which is similar to `merge` and `dplyr::left_join` but with pattern-matches.

```r
ptns <- data.frame(
  ID_ptn = c("^KBS_2015_08_25.*P\\d", "^KBS_2015_09_04.*P\\d",
             "^UMBS_2015_08_12.*P\\d", "^UMBS_2015_08_29.*P\\d"),
  ID_new = c("8/25/2015", "9/4/2015", "8/12/2015", "8/29/2015")
)

fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(df1, ptns, by = c("ID" = "ID_ptn"))
#                      ID Site                ID_ptn    ID_new
# 1  KBS_2015_08_25_A1_P1  KBS ^KBS_2015_08_25.*P\\d 8/25/2015
# 2 KBS_2015_08_25_A2_P10  KBS ^KBS_2015_08_25.*P\\d 8/25/2015
# 3  KBS_2015_09_04_A2_P2  KBS ^KBS_2015_09_04.*P\\d  9/4/2015
```

Expanding this to the larger list can be done with:

```r
lapply(df_list, function(df) {
  tmp <- fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(df, ptns, by = c("ID" = "ID_ptn"))
  tmp$ID <- replace(tmp$ID, !is.na(tmp$ID_new), tmp$ID_new)
  tmp[ names(ptns) ] <- NULL
  tmp
})
# $df1
#          ID Site
# 1 8/25/2015  KBS
# 2 8/25/2015  KBS
# 3  9/4/2015  KBS
# $df2
#          ID Site
# 1 8/12/2015 UMBS
# 2 8/29/2015 UMBS
# 3 8/29/2015 UMBS
```

This is an alternative to the more straight-forward (and perhaps easier-to-see-and-understand) answer by @akrun. I offer it as a different way of looking at the problem.

(I will offer one caution: if it is possible that patterns may overlap, where two or more patterns could match a single `ID`, then some more steps need to be taken to determine which one to use. This will evidence as some rows *repeating* and the number of rows increasing through the join. This is not likely given the current patterns, but ... caveat emptor.)